# Speed up login after changing user name datastore type to VARBINARY from VARCHAR

Tags: 7, database, performance

We have a project underway that requires the import of ~6 million users into Drupal (Core 7x) that have many (150K+) case-insensitive duplicate usernames. Importing these users with existing case and allowing them to log in thereafter (case-sensitive) has been deemed mission-critical by stakeholders, and it's a must-include feature. To facilitate this, I've changed the data type on the users table to VARBINARY from VARCHAR, which allows duplicate usernames with different case, and imported all users successfully.

After making this change, the problem now is that logging in takes a very long time (9-14 seconds) under no server load. Are there ways to speed this up and/or make any change necessary that can significantly improve the performance?

Index on the user table does include name. Picture attached.
[image: db indexes]